# Checking permission before using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

One of my earlier version of iOS app uses `UIImagePickerController`. During that development period there's no permissions involved to access the photos/videos from album. But in latest version, it asks for permission of user to access album.
How can I check if the user has granted permission for accessing the photo album on the device with the help of `UIImagePickerController` (not using `ALAssetLibrary`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update:

Since the PhotoKit framework was introduced in iOS 8 the best way to determine status is on `PHPhotoLibrary`.

Objective-C:

```c
[PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];
```

Swift:

```swift
PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
```

---

There isn't anything in the public interface for `UIImagePickerController` that could be used to determine photo data authorization status. Alas, it seems the only option for determining authorization status is `+[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]`.

Comment: For iOS 10, this is now PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

Comment: @JordanSmith your recommendation is even applicable for iOS 8+.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.